# Hijri Calendar in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to display some dates in the Hijri format in my Windows Phone 8 application.
I found these classes [HijriCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hijricalendar%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [CalendarIdentifiers.Hijri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.calendaridentifiers.hijri)

but they don't support Windows Phone 8.

are there any alternatives ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, using [`CalendarSystem.GetIslamicCalendar`](http://nodatime.org/unstable/api/html/M_NodaTime_CalendarSystem_GetIslamicCalendar.htm) to get the relevant calendar.

Now, that may well have limitations in terms of:

- The rest of your application would ideally want to use Noda Time throughout, to avoid converting all over the place
- If the Hijri calendar isn't supported in WP8, the month names etc may *also* not be supported, so you may need to include those yourself.